# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Tags: apt, path, java, macos

Whenever I try to run any `apt` command on my Mac I get

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

error.

My `.bash_profile` looks as below:

```
Export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `JAVA_HOME` to:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

In case it's not helping try set JAVA_HOME to this command **output**:

`/usr/libexec/java_home`

Answer (score 0):

The apt tool has apparently been removed starting in Java 8. See additional explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847716/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-library-java-javavirtualmachines